# Android fragments casting issue

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to convert my app to a fragments based app. I am trying to load a fragment from a list item , each list item will point to a different fragment class.

In portrait mode, it correctly loads the activities, however in landscape it crashes when attempting to load the fragment class assosciate with the list item.

```
if(index == 0){

            if (mDualPane) {
                // We can display everything in-place with fragments, so update
                // the list to highlight the selected item and show the data.
                // We keep highlighted the current selection
                getListView().setItemChecked(index, true);

                // Check what fragment is currently shown, replace if needed.
                LockingFragment details = (LockingFragment) getFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.details);
                if (details == null || details.getShownIndex() != index) {
                    // Make new fragment to show this selection.

                    details = LockingFragment.newInstance(index);


                    // Execute a transaction, replacing any existing fragment
                    // with this one inside the frame.
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.details, details);
                    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                    ft.commit();
                }

            } else {

                Intent intent = new Intent();


                intent.setClass(getActivity(), LockingActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("index", index);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

            if(index == 1){

            if (mDualPane) {
                // We can display everything in-place with fragments, so update
                // the list to highlight the selected item and show the data.
                // We keep highlighted the current selection
                getListView().setItemChecked(index, true);

                // Check what fragment is currently shown, replace if needed.
                LocateFragment details = (LocateFragment) getFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.details);
                if (details == null || details.getShownIndex() != index) {
                    // Make new fragment to show this selection.

                    details = LocateFragment.newInstance(index);


                    // Execute a transaction, replacing any existing fragment
                    // with this one inside the frame.
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.details, details);
                    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                    ft.commit();
                }

            } else {

                Intent intent = new Intent();


                intent.setClass(getActivity(), LocateActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("index", index);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```

Logcat shows an error that the first fragment cannot be cast to the second.

Here is the logcat

```
08-08 15:26:58.267: E/AndroidRuntime(23927): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-08 15:26:58.267: E/AndroidRuntime(23927): Process: edu.dartmouth.cs, PID: 23927
08-08 15:26:58.267: E/AndroidRuntime(23927): java.lang.ClassCastException: edu.dartmouth.cs.LockingFragment cannot be cast to edu.dartmouth.cs.LocateFragment
08-08 15:26:58.267: E/AndroidRuntime(23927):    at edu.dartmouth.cs.FragmentLayout$TitlesFragment.showDetails(FragmentLayout.java:148)
08-08 15:26:58.267: E/AndroidRuntime(23927):    at edu.dartmouth.cs.FragmentLayout$TitlesFragment.onListItemClick(FragmentLayout.java:91)
08-08 15:26:58.267: E/AndroidRuntime(23927):    at android.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:160)
08-08 15:26:58.267: E/AndroidRuntime(23927):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:308)
08-08 15:26:58.267: E/AndroidRuntime(23927):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1524)
08-08 15:26:58.267: E/AndroidRuntime(23927):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3531)
08-08 15:26:58.267: E/AndroidRuntime(23927):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4898)
08-08 15:26:58.267: E/AndroidRuntime(23927):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-08 15:26:58.267: E/AndroidRuntime(23927):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-08 15:26:58.267: E/AndroidRuntime(23927):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-08 15:26:58.267: E/AndroidRuntime(23927):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
08-08 15:26:58.267: E/AndroidRuntime(23927):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-08 15:26:58.267: E/AndroidRuntime(23927):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-08 15:26:58.267: E/AndroidRuntime(23927):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
08-08 15:26:58.267: E/AndroidRuntime(23927):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
08-08 15:26:58.267: E/AndroidRuntime(23927):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have loaded LockingFragment, which you are trying to cast to LocateFragment. You can check its type before casting, ie:

```
Fragment currentfrag = getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.details);
if (currentfrag instanceof LocateFragment) {
    // here replace current fragment to LockingFragment if needed
 }
```

Comment: Almost have it ... now if i click item two it correctly loads locatefragment, however if I click item one, it fails to loads lockingfragment .... i tried the same as above then both fragments where blank

Comment: Fixed it, had to put a check in for currentfrag being equal to null ... many thanks